# KineticJS and VS2012

Tags: kineticjs

I've been working for weeks on project using KineticJS, no problems. Just a few minutes ago it started throwing errors when I build and debug my page(s).

This is the error:
Unhandled exception at line 2258, column 13 in /scripts/kinetic-v4.0.3.js

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

I don't know what's going on, it happens on any page with KineticJS in any project...

I can go open the pages up in firefox staright out the folder and evrything works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

are you using an older IE browser?  The indexOf method isn't supported in IE6 or IE7 (neither is canvas though)

Comment: Nope, all the newest versions... I don't know what's going on, i may have inadvertently changed a setting in VS 2012 or something... Notice that it's a JScript error, not Javascript...

Comment: sounds like a problem with VS, because the indexOf method is definitely supported in modern browsers (all of the browsers that support canvas at least)

Comment: I noticed I had lost my CSS3 styling in IE9 as well. I spent yesterday afternoon trying to track down what had happened, but found nothing. A system restore fixed it. But it was a last resort measure. This is the second time I've had an issue with VS2012 and IE9 doing something like this. If I weren't using cross domain JSON calls I could've just continued on using chrome or firefox to debug, but that was not the case so I had to find a fix.

Comment: :( I know I'll get crap for this, but it's the truth.  I can't wait for Microsoft to finally quit twitching and actually die off some day.

Comment: When you open a page from your local file system, IE9 sometimes opens up in compatibility mode (dropping to IE7 or lower..), which breaks a lot of stuff. If it does happen again, you could check for that.

Comment: @Eric - is kineticjs support ie7 & 8 browser pls change kineticjs work with older browser because still more people using older browser only

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's largest customer base for Internet Explorer is the enterprise.  Enterprises have invested countless dollars and hours creating intranet applications for older versions of IE that would break under the newer/more standards-compliant versions.  Therefore, for web sites detected in the Local Intranet zone, IE will default to compatibility mode to make IE9 behave like IE7.

Localhost happens to be Local Intranet by default.  This is likely why none of the newer JavaScript objects and methods are available when F5 debugging from Visual Studio, despite using IE9.

Fortunately, there are some things that you can do.  The easiest for an app developer is to just include a meta tag in the page header that tells IE to ignore compatibility mode when rendering that page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

The preferred approach would probably be to have the web server include this header in every HTTP response for that web application.  Either configure IIS to do it, or include the following in the web.config (for IIS7+, I believe):

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         <remove name="X-UA-Compatible"/>
         <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: +1 nice Jason!  Very in depth.  Very glad to have a MS guru helping us out :)